# php check isset from array

Tags: php, variables, foreach, isset

I'm trying to check if a variable is existing, and if not - then define it.

```
$checkarray = array($demo1, $demo2, $demo3);

foreach ($checkarray as $checkkey) {
  if (!isset($checkkey)) {
    $checkkey = 'none';
  }
}
```

But I'm just getting this error: *Notice: Undefined variable: demo1 *(and so on...)*

This is bascially what i'm trying to achive...

```
if (!isset($demo1)) {
  $demo1 = 'none';
 }

if (!isset($demo2)) {
  $demo2 = 'none';
 }

if (!isset($demo3)) {
 $demo3 = 'none';
}
```

But it's not pretty.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Kris

Comment: Well you obviously can not put variables into an array that might not even exist ... What you could do, is put only the variable _names_ or array _keys_ to look for into an array that you then loop over ... but this would make more sense, if your input was in the form of an array already. _Variable variables_ help you perform the check if you need this for real variables, and not arrays.

Comment: If you're just looking to see if the value exists, check out [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: @CBroe you are right. Variable variables was the way to go. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the var name in your check array and not the var itself. This is called [Variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Then you can do something like this :

```
$checkarray = array('demo1', 'demo2', 'demo3');

foreach ($checkarray as $checkkey) {
  if (!isset($$checkkey)) {
    $$checkkey = 'none';
  }
}
```